# How to create custom validation based on xml in .net 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0

I am trying to perform validation using custom class attributes. I have to keep my model validation rules inside XML files. Custom Class attribute specifies the path to the XML file and custom attributes will contain the logic to read XML files and get the validation rules for that class. When I will call Model.Isvalidate() that time Validation will get executed. I already have this working in .Net 4.5 MVC application. The same thing I am trying in .Net 6 its not working.

```
public class CustomDynamicModelValidatorProvider : DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider,IModelValidatorProvider
{
    protected override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, IEnumerable<ModelValidatorProvider> validatorProviders, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        string resourceKeyPath = string.Empty;
        IList<Attribute> newAttributes = new List<Attribute>(attributes);
        CustomDynamicValidatorsAttribute resourceMapperAttr = attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a is CustomDynamicValidatorsAttribute) as CustomDynamicValidatorsAttribute;

        if (resourceMapperAttr == null)
        {
            System.Reflection.MemberInfo classInfo = metadata.ContainerType;
            if (classInfo != null)
            {
                var resourceMapperRootAttr = classInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ResourceMappingRootAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as ResourceMappingRootAttribute;
                if (resourceMapperRootAttr != null)
                {
                    resourceKeyPath = resourceMapperRootAttr.Path + "." + metadata.PropertyName;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            resourceKeyPath = resourceMapperAttr.ResourceKeyPath;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceKeyPath))
        {
            string[] validators = ResourceManager.GetValidators(resourceKeyPath).Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
            var maxLength = ResourceManager.GetMaxLength(resourceKeyPath);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(maxLength))
            {
                var required = new MaxLengthAttribute(maxLength.ToInteger());
                required.ErrorMessage = string.Format(CustomAttributeHelper.GetResourceText("Shared.Messages.MaximumLengthExceeded"), maxLength);
                newAttributes.Add(required);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < validators.Length; i++)
            {
                if (string. Equals(validators[i], "required", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var required = new CustomRequiredAttribute();
                    newAttributes.Add(required);
                }
                else if (validators[i].StartsWith("email", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var email = new CustomEmailAttribute();
                    newAttributes.Add(email);
                }
               
            }
        }

        return base.GetValidators(metadata,validatorProviders);
    }

    public static IDictionary<string, object> GetValidatorAttributes(string validators)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        string[] validatorList = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(validators) ? validators.Replace(" ", "").Split(',') : new string[] { };
        foreach (var item in validatorList)
        {
            if (!attributes.Keys.Contains("data-val"))
            {
                attributes.Add("data-val", "true");
            }
            if (string.Equals(item, "required", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                attributes.Add("data-val-required", CustomAttributeHelper.GetResourceText("Shared.Messages.Mandatory"));
            }
            else if (item.StartsWith("email", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                attributes.Add("data-val-email", CustomAttributeHelper.GetResourceText("Shared.Messages.vEmailField"));
            }
            else if (item.StartsWith("phone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                attributes.Add("data-val-phone", CustomAttributeHelper.GetResourceText("Shared.Messages.vPhoneField"));
            }
            else if (item.StartsWith("zipcode", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                attributes.Add("data-val-zipcode", CustomAttributeHelper.GetResourceText("Shared.Messages.vZipCodeField"));
            }
            else if (item.StartsWith("mark", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                string min = string.Empty;
                string max = string.Empty;
                string rangeValidatorMessage = string.Empty;
                if (item.Contains("-"))
                {
                    var rangeArray = item.Split('-');
                    if (rangeArray.Length > 2)
                    {
                        min = rangeArray[1];
                        max = rangeArray[2];
                        rangeValidatorMessage = CustomAttributeHelper.GetResourceText("Shared.Messages.NumberRange");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        max = rangeArray[1];
                        rangeValidatorMessage = CustomAttributeHelper.GetResourceText("Shared.Messages.vNumericLimited");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    max = "10000";
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(min))
                {
                    attributes.Add("data-val-range-min", min);
                }
                attributes.Add("data-val-range-max", max);
                attributes.Add("data-val-range", rangeValidatorMessage);
            }
            else if (item.StartsWith("number", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                attributes.Add("data-val-number", CustomAttributeHelper.GetResourceText("Shared.Messages.NumberRange"));
            }
            else if (item.StartsWith("number", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                attributes.Add("data-val-decimal", string.Format(CustomAttributeHelper.GetResourceText("Shared.Messages.DecimalRange"), CustomAttributeHelper.GetResourceText("Shared.Limits.Decimal")));
            }
            else if (item.StartsWith("file-", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                attributes.Add("data-val-filetype", item.Split('-')[1]);
            }
        }
        return attributes;
    }

    public void CreateValidators(ModelValidatorProviderContext context)
    { 
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Is not working? How so? What errors do you get? Or otherwise how does it not meet your expectations?

Comment: Its not getting called. I configured like this. **. services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                config.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomExceptionHandler));

            }).AddDataAnnotationsLocalization().AddMvcOptions(options =>
            {
                
                options.ModelValidatorProviders.Add(new CustomDynamicModelValidatorProvider());
            });  **